turn off link time code generation messages in visual studio
When I compile my C++ project with visual studio I get hundreds of messages like this:
4>--- Analyzing function: struct foo::vec3 const __cdecl foo::vec3::operator*(struct foo::matrix3x3 const & __ptr64)const __ptr64
4>C:\Users\Chifti\Project1\foo.h(414) : info C5003: block vectorized

I know they're proud of their optimizer but how can I turn them off? They're very distracting.
